# Why I can't use T? as a generic parameter in C#

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I use `.NET` 5 in `.NET Core` Console Application. The following code can't be compiled:

```
public class NullableClass<T?> 
{ 
}
```

The error is:

> Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected.

It doesn't matter whether I use any constraint.

But this code compiles:

```
[return: MaybeNull]
public static T? Find<T>(IEnumerable<T?> sequence, Func<T?, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var element in sequence) {
        if (predicate(element)) return element;
    }
    return default(T?);
}
```

When I declare `Find<T?>` I have the same error.
What don't I understand here?

Comment: What do you mean by the code `class NullableClass<T?>`?

Comment: @Sweeper: I mean a nullable reference type, they are introduced in c#9

Comment: You mean, you want to allow nullable reference types to be put into the `<>` of `NullableClass`?

Comment: @Sweeper: yes, I'm learning nullable reference types usage and I trying to understand why I can't do things like Find<T?>. I want to understand why it is not allowed: is that some bug in C# or I do miss something and don't understand. By the way, the error message looks strange, it doesn't restrict it directly, it just asks for ",", what is strange.

Comment: Because T always has to be a defined. Your method `Find<T>` forces T to be defined, just as `NullableClass<T>` does. Now, that doesn't mean that T can't be defined as a nullable type.

Comment: Nitpicking: nullable reference types were introduced in c# 8, not 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `T` to be a nullable reference type, you should use a [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for that:

> where T : class?
> The type argument must be a reference type, either nullable or
> non-nullable. This constraint applies also to any class, interface,
> delegate, or array type.

```
public class NullableClass<T> where T : class?
{ 
    // code here
}
```

Note the question mark is a part of the constraint - there's also a constraint for `class` (without the question mark) meaning "reference type", and in c# 8 or higher meaning "non-nullable reference type".

Comment: Thank you. It works, I tried both variants: var nr = new NullableClass<string?>();
            var sequence = new List<string?>() { null, null, "text here" };
            var result = Find<string?>(sequence, x => x != null); It compiles and correctly returns the last element in the sequence.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about where types can be used.

You are not supposed to use/write a *type* here:

```
public class NullableClass<   >
                           ^^^
```

or here:

```
public static T? Find<   >(IEnumerable<T?> sequence, Func<T?, bool> predicate)
                      ^^^
```

Syntactically, these places are the `type_parameters`. You should declare type parameters there, rather than to use an existing type. `public class Foo<List<int>>` makes no sense, right?

From the language spec, this is the syntax for a [class declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes):

```
class_declaration
    : attributes? class_modifier* 'partial'? 'class' identifier type_parameter_list?
      class_base? type_parameter_constraints_clause* class_body ';'?
    ;
```

[`type_parameter_list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#type-parameters) is:

```
type_parameter_list
    : '<' type_parameters '>'
    ;

type_parameters
    : attributes? type_parameter
    | type_parameters ',' attributes? type_parameter
    ;

type_parameter
    : identifier
    ;
```

So really, type parameters are just identifiers, just like variable names in a variable declaration. `T?` is not an identifier. In a `type_parameter_list`, you are just declaring what type parameters this class/method will have.

Now let's look at where types *are* used.

```
public static T? Find<T>(IEnumerable<T?> sequence, Func<T?, bool> predicate)
              ^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

These are all types, so you can use `T?` in those places. The method return type is obviously a type, so you can use a type there. The `<>` I marked above are part of a type, so they are `type_argument_list`s, not `type_parameter_list`s. You can use types in [`type_argument_list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#type-arguments)s:

```
type_name
    : namespace_or_type_name
    ;

namespace_or_type_name
    : identifier type_argument_list?
    | namespace_or_type_name '.' identifier type_argument_list?
    | qualified_alias_member
    ;

type_argument_list
    : '<' type_arguments '>'
    ;

type_arguments
    : type_argument (',' type_argument)*
    ;

type_argument
    : type
    ;
```

---

If you want to allow both nullable and non-nullable reference types to be used as the type argument for the type parameter `T`, use the `class?` [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
class NullableClass<T> where T: class? { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Upvote Sweeper, if you want to use a nullable type, you don't need to have the ? on the definitions, i.e.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        int?[] valueList = new int?[] { 1, null, 3, 4, 5, null };
        int? val = NullableClass<int?>.Find(valueList, new Func<int?, bool>(test));
    }
    public static bool test(int? testMe)
    {
        // Do something productive here
        if (testMe != null && testMe % 2 == 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class NullableClass<T> {
    public static T Find<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        foreach (var element in sequence)
        {
            if (predicate(element)) return element;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP stated that he wants to define nullable *reference* type parameter "I mean a nullable reference type, they are introduced in"